# How to use JPA2's @Cacheable instead of Hibernate's @Cache

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, caching, jpa-2.0

Typically , I use Hibernate's **@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)** to cache an @Entity class , and it works well.

In JPA2 , there's another @Cacheable annotation that seems to be the same functionality with Hibernate's @Cache. To make my entity class independent of hibernate's package , I want to give it a try. But I cannot make it work. Each time a simple id query still hits the DB.

Can anybody tell me where goes wrong ? Thanks.

Entity class :

```
@Entity
//@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Cacheable(true) 
public class User implements Serializable
{
 // properties
}
```

Test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:app.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager")
public class UserCacheTest
{
  @Inject protected UserDao userDao;

  @Transactional
  @Test
  public void testGet1()
  {
    assertNotNull(userDao.get(2L));
  }

  @Transactional
  @Test
  public void testGet2()
  {
    assertNotNull(userDao.get(2L));
  }

  @Transactional
  @Test
  public void testGet3()
  {
    assertNotNull(userDao.get(2L));
  }
}
```

The test result shows each "get" hits DB layer (with hibernate.show_sql=true).

Persistence.xml :

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.use_outer_join" value="true"/>

<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheProvider"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
```

JPA code :

```
@Override
public T get(Serializable id)
{
  return em.find(clazz, id);
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

According to the JPA 2.0 specification, if you want to selectively cache entities using the `@Cacheable` annotation, you're supposed to specify a `<shared-cache-mode>` in the `persistence.xml` (or the equivalent `javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode`  when creating the `EntityManagerFactory`).

Below, a sample `persistence.xml` with the relevant element and properties:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="FooPu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    ...
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      ...
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Note that I've seen at least one issue [HHH-5303](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5303) related to caching. So the above is not guaranteed :)

#### References

- Hibernate EntityManager reference guide

  - [2.2.1 Packaging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration-packaging)
- JPA 2.0 Specification

  - Section 3.7.1 "The shared-cache-mode Element"
  - Section 11.1.7 "Cacheable Annotation"

Comment: Thank you , and it seems still not working in 3.5.5-Final. Anyway , I'll keep an eye on HHH-5303. Thanks.

Comment: These instructions worked for me using 3.5.5-Final and ehcache 2.3.1

Comment: It may not work with 3.5.5 because I think JPA 2.0 is supported by hibernate 4.0 it self.

Answer (score 11):

For those who use Spring config instead of `persistence.xml`, here is a sample:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mycompany.myproject.domain"/>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
            <entry key="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Also note that if you're using `@Cacheable` annotations, you can only use a default cache concurrency strategy, which is determined by the `getDefaultAccessType()` method of the `RegionFactory`. In case of EhCache it's [READ_WRITE](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-ehcache/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cache/ehcache/AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory.java). If you want to use another strategy, you have to use Hibernate's `@Cache` annotations.

Comment: what is <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/> used for? will it use hibernate's cache?

Comment: @Scarlett It specifies which caching implementation Hibernate will use for the second level cache. It’s described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-cache).

Comment: NOTE: Since 4.0 on, it is possible to config default strategy globally, without depending on hibernate package in code, see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch06.html