# Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given JPA+hibernate+Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, second-level-cache

Hi this question has been asked so many times but still In my application second level cache is not able to configure. I am using JPA+hibernate+Spring , I have tried the possible ways to configure but unsuccessful.

These are the links found for configuration

[How to configure JPA 2.0 with Hibernate 3.5.2 to use EHCache as a Level 2 cache and query cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674697/how-to-configure-jpa-2-0-with-hibernate-3-5-2-to-use-ehcache-as-a-level-2-cache)

This is my error

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:16)
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory.buildEntityRegion(NoCachingRegionFactory.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
```

This is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">


    <persistence-unit name="ornament" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <mapping-file>domain/orm/Category.orm.xml</mapping-file>
        <!-- <mapping-file>META-INF/product.orm.xml</mapping-file> -->
        <class>com.ornamentbazzar.common.catalog.entity.Category</class>
        <class>com.ornamentbazzar.common.catalog.entity.CategoryMapper</class>
        <class>com.ornamentbazzar.common.catalog.entity.CategoryMapperPK</class>
        <class>com.ornamentbazzar.common.catalog.entity.CategoryAttribute</class>
        <class>com.ornamentbazzar.common.catalog.entity.CategoryMapper</class>
        <class>com.ornamentbazzar.common.assets.entity.StaticAsset</class>
        <class>com.ornamentbazzar.common.assets.entity.StaticAssetDescription</class>
        <class>com.ornamentbazzar.common.assets.entity.ImageStaticAsset</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true" />
             <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>

             <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>    
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration" value="category-ehcache.xml" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

applicationContext-persistence.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="***" />
    <property name="password" value="***" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
    proxy-target-class="true" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:* META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ornament" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ornamentbazzar.*" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.9.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Hibernate Libraries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Class which is used for cache

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
 import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region = "categories")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(Category.class);

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "CategoryId")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "CategoryId", strategy = "com.ornamentbazzar.common.util.CustomTableGenerator", parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "segment_value", value = "CategoryImpl"),
            @Parameter(name = "entity_name", value = "com.ornamentbazzar.common.catalog.entity.Category") })
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    @Index(name = "CATEGORY_NAME_INDEX", columnNames = { "NAME" })
    protected String name;

    @Column(name = "URL")
    @Index(name = "CATEGORY_URL_INDEX", columnNames = { "URL" })
    protected String url;

    @Column(name = "URL_KEY")
    @Index(name = "CATEGORY_URLKEY_INDEX", columnNames = { "URL_KEY" })
    protected String urlKey;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    protected String description;
}
```

Main class for testing

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                new String[] { "applicationContext-persistence.xml" });
        CategoryDao categoryDao = (CategoryDaoImpl) applicationContext
                .getBean("CategoryDao");
        Category category = categoryDao.findCategoryByName("jewellery");
        System.out.println(category.getDescription());
}
}
```

directory

[image]

Comment: Is your Spring config file called applicationContext-persistence.xml or applicationContext-persitent.xml? You've referred to both.

Comment: @alex actually its applicationContext-persistence.xml i am referring to spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line looks broken

```
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:* META-INF/persistence.xml" />
```

The `*` looks spurious. Or looks like it was meant to be `classpath*:`, which would merge all `persistence.xml` found on your classpath, including JARs, though I'm not sure why you'd want that.

The line also refers to `persistence.xml`, even though your question used `persistent.xml`. So would start by checking that.

Comment: Thanks for replying the error  was with classpath*: