# Hibernate+Spring Data JPA Second Level cache XML

Tags: hibernate, caching, spring-data, ehcache

I use `spring data JPA` and `Hibernate` remix in my project.
Recently,I encounter performance issue.
I want to add Hibernate annotation `@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)` in my Entity Class for second level cache.
When start the tomcat,it's throws `Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given, please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory class name to property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class (and make sure the second level cache provider, hibernate-infinispan, for example, is available in the classpath).`.

my spring-jpa.mxl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"> 
        <!-- use annotation in Service: @Transactional -->

    <bean id="transactionManager2" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
         <qualifier value="transactionManager2"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oracleConnection" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/OracleDB</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oracleTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleConnection" />
         <qualifier value="oracleConnectionTransactionManager"/>
    </bean>



    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"  />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="mssqlDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url">
            <value>${connection.url}</value> 
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>${connection.username}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${connection.1qaz@WSX}</value>
        </property>    
    </bean>


    <bean id="auditInterceptor" class="com.bot.gnweb.unit.AuditIntercepter"/>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="mssqlDataSource" />
        <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="auditInterceptor"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <value>com.bot.gnweb.model</value>
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
           <list>
               <value>gnwebSql.xml</value>
           </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">com.bot.gnweb.model.MssqlCustomDialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehcache.xml</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            </props>  
        </property>
    </bean>



    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" depends-on="auditInterceptor">
        <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="gnWebPU" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="mssqlDataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Spring Data -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.bot.gnweb.repository"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
        transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="auditorBean" class="com.bot.gnweb.model.AuditingAware" />
    <jpa:auditing auditor-aware-ref="auditorBean" />


</beans>
```

and my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="gnWebPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />            
            <property name="format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="default-schema" value="dbo" />
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="com.bot.gnweb.unit.AuditIntercepter" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and my project xml path
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is literally in the error message:

> Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given, please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory class name to property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class (and make sure the second level cache provider, hibernate-infinispan, for example, is available in the classpath).

You havn't configured `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class`

so add a line like the following to your `persistence.xml`

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
```

You can read more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3675579/66686

Comment: I put,and the problem still is same.Can you tell me what I lose

Comment: Is your cache provider implementation in the classpath? Do you still see exactly the same error?