# How do I migrate cache related annotations from Hibernate 3.3.x to 3.6.x

Tags: hibernate, caching, jpa, jpa-2.0, second-level-cache

My cache usage on entity Foo looked like this

```
@Entity
class Foo {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @Cache(usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Boo boo;

    @OneToMany
    @Cache(usage = org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    private List<Bar> bars;
}
```

How should I migrate this code to support JPA 2 like annotations using Hibernate 3.6.5

I am aware that we are supposed to use `@Cacheable` annotation at the entity level, but what should I use for cache declarations under

```
@ManyToOne and @OneToMany.
```

Comment: JPA2 doesn't define caching specifics for fields/properties, just classes; JDO is the only persistence spec defining caching down to the field level

Answer (score 0):

Remove your @Cache annotations and add to your persistence.xml :

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="FooPu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    ...
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      ...
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**References**

- [How to use JPA2's @Cacheable instead of Hibernate's @Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663979/how-to-use-jpa2s-cacheable-instead-of-hibernates-cache)

Comment: No, sorry that doesn't answer the question. The question is asking about how to annotate collections for caching.