# Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

This post is in continuation of [JPA How to get the value from database after persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856917/jpa-how-to-get-the-value-from-database-after-persist)

When I execute the following I am getting following exception, how can I resolve this?

```
Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring 
transactions or EJB CMT
```

**DAOImpl** code

```
public void create(Project project) {
        entityManager.persist(project);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        project = entityManager.find(Project.class, project.getProjectId());
        entityManager.refresh(project);
        System.out.println("Id    -- " + project.getProjectId());
            System.out.println("no -- " + project.getProjectNo());
    }
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="DataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="username" value="scott" />
        <property name="password" value="tiger" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver:1521:ORCL" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="test.entity" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="test.net" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> 

     <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>         

     <context:annotation-config/>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I guess the problem here is that although you have defined the bean for the transaction manager, you haven't annotated the create() method with `@Transactional` which enables spring transactions.

Also remove the `entityManager.getTransaction().commit();` statement as now all the transaction management will be handled by spring, if you leave the statement as it is then you will get the same error again.

Comment: when you autowire the entitymanager with @PersistenceContext i still get the same error even when i annotate the method with Transactional and remove the commit statement

Comment: Like maurice said, this doesnt resolve my issue. I get :javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query" error

Answer (score 35):

Injecting EntityManagerFactory instead of EntityManager and javax.transaction.Transactional annotation on method solved my issue as shown below.

```
//Autowire EntityManagerFactory
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "readwrite.config")
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;


//Use below code on create/update
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(entity) && !entityManager.contains(entity)) {
   entityManager.persist(entity);
   entityManager.flush();
}
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: This resolved my problem but my only question is if we can create entityManager from entityManagerFactory as a class member property and use it in different methods that I have forexample in my dao class?

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'readwrite.config' available

Comment: This solved my problem. But how why @Transactaional annotation not working instead of begin()??

Comment: @geneb. you put 'default' instead 'readwrite.config'

Comment: It will work without mentioning `(unitName = "readwrite.config")` as well otherwise it will give error

Comment: This is great and all, but in my case the database is not updated when I call commit its not updating the database directly, well at least its not waiting on the current thread to do so and this is quite important seeing that the db has more than 100k records and the user needs to get notified once its done so that they can view the records on the web application. Does anyone have any suggestions for my use case?

Answer (score 9):

You need to remove the statement `entityManager.getTransaction().begin() and annotate the method using` @Transactional? which enables transaction handling by Spring.

Answer (score 3):

In my case inside Sping-boot this solution worked

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
public void myMethod() {

    SessionImplementor sessionImp = (SessionImplementor) em.getDelegate();
    var transaction = sessionImp.getTransaction();
    for (MyClass cls : lst) {
        try {
            transaction.begin();
            //do my stuffs with em
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```