# Spring or hibernate crash while it's trying add a new entity to the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the next data model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Tables.USERS, catalog = Database.NAME)
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8190974017668449062L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = Tables.Users.ID, nullable = false)
    @Type(type="pg-uuid")
    private UUID mId;
    @Column(name = Tables.Users.FIRST_NAME, nullable = false)
    private String mFirstName;
    @Column(name = Tables.Users.LAST_NAME, nullable = false)
    private String mLastName;
    @Column(name = Tables.Users.EMAIL, nullable = false)
    private String mEmail;
    @Column(name = Tables.Users.BIRTHDATE, nullable = false)
    @Type(type="date")
    private Date mBirthdate;
    @Column(name = Tables.Users.SEX, nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Sex mSex;
    @Column(name = Tables.Users.HASH, nullable = false, length = 32)
    private String mHash;
    @Column(name = Tables.Users.SALT, nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String mSalt;

    public UUID getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public User setId(final UUID id) {
        mId = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return mFirstName;
    }

    public User setFirstName(final String firstName) {
        mFirstName = firstName;
        return this;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return mLastName;
    }

    public User setLastName(final String lastName) {
        mLastName = lastName;
        return this;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return mEmail;
    }

    public User setEmail(final String email) {
        mEmail = email;
        return this;
    }

    public Date getBirthdate() {
        return mBirthdate;
    }

    public User setBirthdate(Date birthdate) {
        mBirthdate = birthdate;
        return this;
    }

    public Sex getSex() {
        return mSex;
    }

    public User setSex(Sex sex) {
        mSex = sex;
        return this;
    }

    public String getHash() {
        return mHash;
    }

    public User setHash(String hash) {
        mHash = hash;
        return this;
    }

    public String getSalt() {
        return mSalt;
    }

    public User setSalt(String salt) {
        mSalt = salt;
        return this;
    }
}
```

My `EntityManager` is:

```
@Service
public class UserManager implements IUserManager {

    private static final int PAGE_SIZE = 10;

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO mDAO;

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return mDAO.getAllUsers();
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers(int pageNumber) {
        return mDAO.getUsers(pageNumber, PAGE_SIZE);
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserByEmail(String email) {
        return mDAO.getUserByEmail(email);
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserById(UUID id) {
        return mDAO.getUserById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasEmail(String email) {
        return mDAO.getUserByEmail(email) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(User user) {
        return mDAO.add(user);
    }
}
```

And my DAO:

```
@Repository
public class UserDAO implements IUserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager mEntityManager;

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = mEntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> cq = builder.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);
        cq.select(root);
        TypedQuery<User> tq = mEntityManager.createQuery(cq);
        return tq.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers(int pageNumber, int pageSize) {

        try {
            CriteriaBuilder builder = mEntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<User> cq = builder.createQuery(User.class);
            Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);
            cq.select(root);
            TypedQuery<User> tq = mEntityManager.createQuery(cq);
            tq.setMaxResults(pageSize);
            tq.setFirstResult((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize);
            return tq.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserByEmail(String email) {

        try {
            CriteriaBuilder builder = mEntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<User> cq = builder.createQuery(User.class);
            Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);
            cq.where(builder.equal(root.get(Tables.Users.EMAIL), email));
            cq.select(root);
            TypedQuery<User> tq = mEntityManager.createQuery(cq);
            return tq.getSingleResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserById(UUID id) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = mEntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> cq = builder.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);
        cq.where(builder.equal(root.get(Tables.Users.ID), id));
        cq.select(root);
        TypedQuery<User> tq = mEntityManager.createQuery(cq);
        return tq.getSingleResult();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(User user) {

        try {
            EntityTransaction transaction = mEntityManager.getTransaction();
            transaction.begin();
            mEntityManager.persist(user);
            transaction.commit();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to add a new user to the database in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("users")
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserManager mUserManager;

    @PostMapping(value = "new")
    public ResponseEntity<UserModel> register(@RequestBody NewUserModel newUser) {
        User user = UserUtils.toUser(mUserManager, newUser);
        user.setId(UUID.randomUUID());

        if (!mUserManager.add(user)) {
            throw new InternalServerException(ServerError.INTERNAL);
        }

        UserModel userModel = new UserModel(user);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(userModel, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

My `UserManager` returns `false` though `User` object is correct. But I have checked it in the debug mode, my manager didn't call even `add()` method from `UserDAO`, instead of it the control was moved to `CglibAopProxy` in the method `intercept`... It goes through this method body and after I am getting `false` return in `UserManager`... I got a nothing just...
Where can I find an error? I haven't ideas even.

Comment: Would appear that Spring is throwing an exception which should definitely be part of the stacktrace. I'd read through the logs. You didnt provide an mvce (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I attempted to put one together based on what you did provide and I tried to fill in the gaps as best I could. When I run a test I get a IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead when executing the add method

Comment: @SeanCarroll Sorry, my English isn't so good... I didn't get how must I make a transaction then?

Comment: First, I'd verify that you're actually getting the same exception that I'm getting. If you are I'd suggest looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860696/not-allowed-to-create-transaction-on-shared-entitymanager-use-spring-transacti

Comment: @SeanCarroll Thank you very much, I'll check now.... In any case I know an error at least cuz my debugger didn't output any exception.

Comment: if you findings don't match mine I'd suggest providing more details around your configuration including datasource