# What is the difference between adding JPA annotations to fields vs getters?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, groovy

I am new to Spring Boot and JPA in general. I've seen examples of adding JPA annotations on field declarations such as this:

```
@Entity
public class Fizz {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // other fields

    public Fizz(Long id) {
        super();

        setId(id);
    }

    // setter defined here

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

...as well as examples putting the same annotations on the getters like this:

```
@Entity
public class Fizz {
    private Long id;

    // other fields

    public Fizz(Long id) {
        super();

        setId(id);
    }

    // setter defined here

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if they are semantically equivalent or if there are different use cases where you'd choose one over the other. I ask because I'm actually writing my Spring Boot/JPA app in Groovy where you typically don't define getters:

```
@Canonical
@Entity
class Fizz {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id
}
```

Answer (score 14):

By default, JPA providers access the values of entity fields and map those fields to database columns
using the entity’s JavaBean property accessor (getter) and mutator (setter) methods. As such, the
names and types of the private fields in an entity do not matter to JPA. Instead, JPA looks at only
the names and return types of the JavaBean property accessors. You can alter this using the `@javax.persistence.Access` annotation, which enables you to explicitly specify the access methodology
that the JPA provider should employ.

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class SomeEntity implements Serializable
{
...
}
```

The available options for the AccessType enum are `PROPERTY` (the default) and `FIELD`. With
`PROPERTY`, the provider gets and sets field values using the JavaBean property methods. `FIELD` makes
the provider get and set field values using the instance fields. As a best practice, you should just stick
to the default and use JavaBean properties unless you have a compelling reason to do otherwise.

You
can put these property annotations on either the private fields or the public accessor methods. If
you use `AccessType.PROPERTY` (default) and annotate the private fields instead of the JavaBean
accessors, the field names must match the JavaBean property names. However, the names do not
have to match if you annotate the JavaBean accessors. Likewise, if you use `AccessType.FIELD` and
annotate the JavaBean accessors instead of the fields, the field names must also match the JavaBean
property names. In this case, they do not have to match if you annotate the fields. It’s best to just
be consistent and annotate the JavaBean accessors for `AccessType.PROPERTY` and the fields for
`AccessType.FIELD`.

You should never mix JPA property annotations and JPA field annotations
in the same entity. Doing so results in unspecified behavior and is very
likely to cause errors.