# Ehcache second level cache not working with JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ehcache

**EDIT:**  I should state that I've been researching this for a couple of days now - there is **plenty** of information on "how to configure ehcache with Hibernate" but they mostly do not refer to using JPA and annotations - they either refer to pure Hibernate or to configuration through XML.  (Just want to make it clear that I have already been around the internet on this problem.)   I'm using JPA and annotations, so most of these configuration guides refer to files I don't have in my app (like hbm.xml files).

I have an app that is using Hibernate 3.6.10.FINAL, Spring Data 1.3.2.RELEASE, and Spring version 3.2.1.RELEASE.   I'm trying to get the second-level caching working in hibernate.   According to the documentation, I can do that simply by including the following dependency and configuration:

(POM.XML)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

(PERSISTENCE.XML)

```
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class"  value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"  />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
```

I've annotated one of my entity classes using the javax.persistence.Cacheable annotation and tried to view the statistics in a JUnit test:

```
public void cacheTest() {
    RandomDataGenerator randomData = new RandomDataGenerator();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        AppMaster master = masterService.findOne(randomData.nextLong(1, 10));
        logger.debug(String.format("Read one record back = %1$d, %2$s", master.getApplicationId(), master.getApContact()),AppMasterServiceTest.class);
        //  Get statistics from hibernate session
        Session session = (Session)masterService.getEntityManager().getDelegate();
        Statistics statistics = session.getSessionFactory().getStatistics();
        logger.debug(String.format("Second level stats = %1$d, %2$d, %3$d", 
                statistics.getSecondLevelCachePutCount(), 
                statistics.getSecondLevelCacheHitCount(),
                statistics.getSecondLevelCacheMissCount()), AppMasterServiceTest.class);
    }
```

But the statistics appear to always be zero.

```
2013-11-11 11:20:33,908 DEBUG [main] test.service.AppMasterServiceTest  - Second level stats = 0, 0, 0
```

Can anyone help me diagnose this?

Comment: From what you've posted it looks like you haven't set ENABLE_SELECTIVE in your persistence.xml. Check out the docs on http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Cacheable.html and take a look at this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663979/how-to-use-jpa2s-cacheable-instead-of-hibernates-cache

Comment: You seem to be correct, adding a tag to specify ENABLE_SELECTIVE explicitly in the persistence.xml seems to have done the trick.   I've read that ENABLE_SELECTIVE should be the default (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration), however I've also read that it seems to not work that way.  If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll be happy to mark it correct!   Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javax.persistence.Cachable requires you set ENABLE_SELECTIVE in your persistence.xml.  You should include a line like the following:

```
<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
```

Check out the docs on http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Cacheable.html

Also, take a look at this related question: [How to use JPA2's @Cacheable instead of Hibernate's @Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663979/how-to-use-jpa2s-cacheable-instead-of-hibernates-cache)

Comment: Just to amplify, ENABLE_SELECTIVE should be the default (you should not need to specify it explicitly), but for some reason you must put this line in your persistence.xml or you get nothing.

Comment: but when specify the <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode> under <persistence-unit>, there will be error in the persistence.xml. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'shared-cache-mode'. 
 "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":non-jta-data-source, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":mapping-file, "http://
 java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":jar-file, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":class, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/
 persistence":exclude-unlisted-classes, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":properties}' is expected.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! That is pretty strange that, like @user1071914 says, the property needs to be set even though hibernate set that that's the default value..